# How can I get the value of IloExprArray variables

Tags: c++, cplex

Here is my snippet of code:

```
for(IloInt h=0; h<Branch; ++h)
{
    Pf[h]=IloExpr(env); 
    Pf[h]+=(Theta[(IloInt)Info_Branch[h][0]-1]-Theta[(IloInt)Info_Branch[h][1]-1])/Info_Branch[h][3];
    Check_Model.add(Pf[h]-S4[h]<=Info_Branch[h][4]);
    Check_Model.add(Pf[h]+S5[h]>=-Info_Branch[h][4]);
}
```

Pf,Theta,S4 and S5 are all IloExprArray variables.
    Now I want to know when the solution can not satisfy the constraints,the value of Pf,S4 and S5.
   They must have values since the variable Info_Branch[h][4] is a number.
But I have no idea how to realize it.

Comment: Are you trying to check values while building your model before solving it; or are you trying to cehck the solution values after solving it?

Comment: I am trying to check the value of Pf,S4,S5 after solving  the model.

Comment: OK, what have you tried. You have shown us the snippet where you create an array of IloExprs. What does your code for getting the values look like so far? And what doesn't work? Are you getting errors at compile time or runtime, or just wrong values?